# Mysql query fetch all rows that matches the user groups is only one

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter-3

I have two tables in mysql database

1.`loc8_users (id,username,password,email,phone`)

2.`loc8_users_groups (id,user_id,group_id).`

Here `loc8_users_groups` store the group id's that assign to each users.

I want to fetch all rows from `loc8_users` table in which a user have only one group

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please give this a try:

```
SELECT 
U.*
FROM loc8_users U
INNER JOIN 
(
    SELECT 
    UG.user_id
    FROM loc8_users_groups UG
    GROUP BY UG.user_id
    HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UG.group_id) = 1
) AS t
ON U.id = t.user_id
```

**Explanation:**

```
SELECT 
 UG.user_id
FROM loc8_users_groups UG
GROUP BY UG.user_id
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT UG.group_id) = 1;
```

This query returns only those `user_id`s who are involved in only one group.

We got those `user_id`s but now we need the user information of those `user_id`s. So making an `INNER JOIN` between this query result and `loc8_users` table on matching `user_id` would do.

Comment: Happy :). Btw, I've added a brief explanation. You might take a look @shammon